# Can you use the BulbFlow (bulbs) Python ORM with OrientDB's Graph Schema Constraints?

Tags: python, orm, graph-databases, orientdb, bulbs

I am building an application which uses [BulbFlow](http://bulbflow.com/).  The BulbFlow ORM is similar to the Django ORM.  As an actual database backend, I am using [OrientDB 1.3.0](http://www.orientdb.org/), with Rexster 2.2.0.

I am wondering if anyone has any insight into using these two products together.  BulbFlow allows for Python-based definitions of your data model.  However OrientDB has its own schema definition system, including classes and constraints.  Is there any way to use them together?  Or is OrientDB's constraint system already being used by Rexster/BulbFlow?

Thanks in advance for the insight.

Answer (score 1):

All Rexster graphs use Blueprints under the hood, and Bulbs' default API/Gremlin scripts treat all Rexster graphs the same so there is no OrientDB-specific code.

However, you can use custom Gremlin scripts to access OrientDB-specific features.

See...

- https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/wiki/OrientDB-Implementation
- https://github.com/nuvolabase/orientdb/wiki/Graph-Schema
- http://bulbflow.com/docs/api/bulbs/gremlin/